# Selenium webscraping app - how to obtain the final download URL from a 302 redirect

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am developing a python app using selenium to scrape images from unsplash.

I am able to get a list of photo URLs with the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://unsplash.com/t/nature")

numberofscrollsdown = 1
scrolldownpixels = 1000

y = scrolldownpixels
for x in range(0, numberofscrollsdown):
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, "+str(y)+")")
    y += scrolldownpixels
    time.sleep(1)

el = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for elm in el:
    elref = elm.get_attribute("href")
    if "/photos/" in elref:
        if not "/download?force=true" in elref:
            image_url = elref + "/download?force=true&w=1920"
```

An example image_url is:

https://unsplash.com/photos/QNBwyf0Cn-g/download?force=true&w=1920

Putting this URL into a browser brings up the "Save Dialog" to save an image locally

Inspecting the page for that URL, there seems to be a 302 redirect to the actual image URL

My issue - how do I obtain the final redirected URL automatically from within the python code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED it...

This code was needed:

```
    r = requests.get(image_url, allow_redirects=True)
    filename = r.headers.get('content-disposition')
    flnm1 = filename.replace('attachment;filename="', '')
    flnm2 = flnm1.replace('"', '')
    with open (flnm2, "wb") as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```